# Write a float in c

Tags: c

I know this is an incredibly basic question but I wanted to check my understanding on something. I want to pass an integer to a function that accepts a float. It will automatically be converted by the function but I want to make it explicit. Are there any additional options to do this?

```
myfunc(2.0);
myfunc((float) 2);
myfunc(2f); <-- any way to do the last one, or is that compiler-specific, or not supported at all?
```

Comment: you can do 2.f, which would make it a float instead of a double. 2.0 is often interpreted as a double instead of a float.

Comment: In C, a floating constant without a suffix, such as `2.0`, *always* has type `double`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I see -- why doesn't the program complain then when it tries to reduce the `double` to a `float` when passing it to another function that receives a float?

Comment: For gcc/clang, `-Wconversion` will warn on `double` to `float` narrowing. VS, `/W3` will do the same.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249, C also specifies that `double` values are automatically converted to `float` as needed in assignment expressions and function calls.  In the function call case, this requires there to be a prototype for the function in scope at the point of the call.  Some compilers will warn under some circumstances, but there is nothing erroneous about such conversions, and nothing obligates compilers to say anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have floating point number in front of the `f`, otherwise compiler will read numerical value as integer and complain.

```
myfunc(2.0f);
```

The above would work.

For whole numbers you have something like:

```
myfunc(2l);
myfunc(2u);
```

Thanks to @user3386109 so floating point suffixes are definitely in in standard `6.4.4.2p4`

Comment: thanks, is that defined in the standard or it's compiler specific?

Comment: Let me check on it, I think it is standard. Perhaps if your function expects type of `long` and you call it with `myfunc(2)` it will pass it integer instead of `long` unless you provide `myfunc(2l)`.

Comment: @CEPB Floating point suffixes are defined in 6.4.4.2p4

Comment: If the prototype for `myfunc` is `void myfunc(long n);` and you call it with `myfunc(2)`, the 2 will be implicitly converted to `long` with or without a suffix.

Comment: @user3386109 damn it, I don't remember, but I think I read that there is difference in between those 2.

Comment: You may be thinking about variadic functions, e.g. `printf`. Variadic function have their own rules about argument conversions, since the function prototype doesn't specify the types for the variadic arguments. For example, `printf("%ld\n", 2);` is wrong, and will result in a warning, because the 2 will be converted to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

C 2018 6.4.4.2 defines a decimal floating-point constant to have either decimal point (`.`) or an exponent part (`e` or `E` followed by a signed integer). It can have a suffix, such as `f` for `float`, but it still must have a decimal point or exponent. So you need one of those two things to make it a floating-point constant rather than an integer constant. You can have `1.2`, `1.`, `.2`, or `1e3` but not `1`.

Hexadecimal floating-point constants also need either a point or an exponent, but the exponent begins with `p` or `P` (and the hexadecimal constant begins with `0x` or `0X`<sup>1</sup>).

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> There is a typo in the C 2018 standard; it shows the hexadecimal prefixes as one of `0X` or `0X`. This was `0x` or `0X` in the 2011 standard, which is undoubtedly the intent.